# SQL update last occurrence

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

I have a simple `SELECT` query that works fine and returns one row, which is the last occurrence of a specific value in `order_id` column. I want to update this row. However, I cannot combine this `SELECT` query with the `UPDATE` query.

This is the working query that returns one row, which I want to update:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id
       ORDER BY start_hour DESC) rn
       FROM general_report
       WHERE order_id = 16836
     ) q
WHERE rn = 1
```

And I tried many combinations to update the row returned by this statement. For example, I tried to remove `SELECT  *`, and update the table `q` as in the following, but it didn't work telling me that relation q does not exist.

```
UPDATE  q
SET q.cost = 550.01685
FROM (
       SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id
       ORDER BY start_hour DESC) rn
       FROM general_report
       WHERE order_id = 16836
     ) q
WHERE rn = 1
```

How can I combine these codes with a correct `UPDATE` syntax? In case needed, I test my codes at SQL Manager for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Your subquery is uncorrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. I am not sure on PostgreSQL syntax:

```
UPDATE general_report AS d 
SET cost  = 550.01685
FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM (
              SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id
              ORDER BY start_hour DESC) rn
              FROM general_report
              WHERE order_id = 16836
             ) q
        WHERE rn = 1
     ) s
WHERE d.id = s.id
```

Comment: You don't need the nested sub-select. You can use `where d.id = s.id and rn = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Ana alternative method for `update the most recent record` is to use `NOT EXISTS (even more recent)`:

```
UPDATE  general_report dst
SET cost = 550.01685
WHERE order_id = 16836
AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM general_report nx
       WHERE nx.order_id = dst.order_id
       AND  nx.start_hour > dst.start_hour
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Test below query

```
UPDATE  q
SET q.cost = 550.01685
where id in  
(select id from
(
       SELECT *
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id
       ORDER BY start_hour DESC) rn
       FROM general_report
       WHERE order_id = 16836
     ) q
WHERE rn = 1)
```

Comment: "relation q does not exist" hatası verdi gene

Comment: That is because the correlation name should not be used on the laft side of `=` (and the table name is `general_report` )